# How to get public Facebook Page data no matter the country/language admin selected?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As you may know, Facebook Page Administrators can select for posts to be visible to only certain countries/langauges ( https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=180817924821 ).

However, I would like to use the Graph API to retrieve feed messages ( /feed ) for ALL countries/languages or be able to select data for a specific country.

For example:

1) I would like to get ALL posts (and comments ...) from all of Starbucks Facebook Page. So no matter what the administrator says, just ALL.

2) I would like to be able to retrieve only the posts that are visible to users in Germany.

Are both these example actually possible? Probably, because I use access_tokens Facebook will probably use my own country/langauge to decide what data I get so that would mean I would have to change country all the time which is of course not an option to ask my users.

Any of you know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible if you're using the app as an admin of the posting page.

As you mentioned, the API will detect the user behind your `access_token` and only display posts that would normally be accessible to them on the desktop site.

This is an intentional restriction, so there's no way around it.

Comment: Thanks, although not the answered I hoped :-)

But you say that if I would be administrator, I can have ALL posts? Even those written by collegues in different countries that post on the same page?

Comment: If you're an admin, you can see every post on the page, regardless of geo-gating.